# Could not parse xml file Help Me

Tags: python, xml, tensorflow

I was following the link below.
https://youtu.be/2XMkPW_sIGg
https://github.com/dusty-nv/jetson-inference/blob/master/docs/pytorch-collect-detection.md

As link tutorial above, I received git clone at https://github.com/dusty-nv/jetson-inference.git first, and then placed the imageset under ssd folder which was photographed and labeled with the camera capture tool (path : jetson-inference/python/training/detection/[ssd](https://nvidia.box.com/shared/static/djf5w54rjvpqocsiztzaandq1m3avr7c.pth)/* )
Then, using the pretrained model [mobileenet-v1-ssd-mp-0_675](https://nvidia.box.com/shared/static/djf5w54rjvpqocsiztzaandq1m3avr7c.pth).pth under ssd/models, the training command below was used to retrain the model.
When I tried to train with the following command, I saw the error message.

```
!python3 train_ssd.py --dataset-type=voc --data=data/jetbot
--model-dir=models/jetbot --batch-size=2 --workers=1 --epochs=1
```

```
2022-11-04 20:43:30 - Namespace(balance_data=False, base_net=None, base_net_lr=0.001, batch_size=2, checkpoint_folder='models/jetbot', dataset_type='voc', datasets=['data/jetbot'], debug_steps=10, extra_layers_lr=None, freeze_base_net=False, freeze_net=False, gamma=0.1, log_level='info', lr=0.01, mb2_width_mult=1.0, milestones='80,100', momentum=0.9, net='mb1-ssd', num_epochs=1, num_workers=1, pretrained_ssd='models/mobilenet-v1-ssd-mp-0_675.pth', resolution=300, resume=None, scheduler='cosine', t_max=100, use_cuda=True, validation_epochs=1, validation_mean_ap=False, weight_decay=0.0005)
2022-11-04 20:43:30 - model resolution 300x300
2022-11-04 20:43:30 - SSDSpec(feature_map_size=19, shrinkage=16, box_sizes=SSDBoxSizes(min=60, max=105), aspect_ratios=[2, 3])
2022-11-04 20:43:30 - SSDSpec(feature_map_size=10, shrinkage=32, box_sizes=SSDBoxSizes(min=105, max=150), aspect_ratios=[2, 3])
2022-11-04 20:43:30 - SSDSpec(feature_map_size=5, shrinkage=64, box_sizes=SSDBoxSizes(min=150, max=195), aspect_ratios=[2, 3])
2022-11-04 20:43:30 - SSDSpec(feature_map_size=3, shrinkage=100, box_sizes=SSDBoxSizes(min=195, max=240), aspect_ratios=[2, 3])
2022-11-04 20:43:30 - SSDSpec(feature_map_size=2, shrinkage=150, box_sizes=SSDBoxSizes(min=240, max=285), aspect_ratios=[2, 3])
2022-11-04 20:43:30 - SSDSpec(feature_map_size=1, shrinkage=300, box_sizes=SSDBoxSizes(min=285, max=330), aspect_ratios=[2, 3])
2022-11-04 20:43:30 - Prepare training datasets.
warning - image 20221031-132300 has no box/labels annotations, ignoring from dataset
warning - image 20221031-132304 has no box/labels annotations, ignoring from dataset
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_ssd.py", line 257, in <module>
    target_transform=target_transform)
  File "/content/jetson-inference/python/training/detection/ssd/vision/datasets/voc_dataset.py", line 36, in __init__
    self.ids = self._read_image_ids(image_sets_file) #202200-000000 shape
  File "/content/jetson-inference/python/training/detection/ssd/vision/datasets/voc_dataset.py", line 112, in _read_image_ids
    if self._get_num_annotations(image_id) > 0: #202200-001234 shape
  File "/content/jetson-inference/python/training/detection/ssd/vision/datasets/voc_dataset.py", line 125, in _get_num_annotations
    objects = ET.parse(annotation_file).findall("object") #202200-001234.xml
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1197, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 598, in parse
    self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

The structure of the model I use when training is as follows.

```
- Annotations/
      - *.xml
- ImageSets/
      - Main
            - test.txt
            - train.txt
            - trainval.txt
            - val.txt
- JPEGImages/
      - *.jpg
- labels.txt
```

As a result of many searches, it is said that it is a problem that occurs when there is a problem with the format or content of the xml file, but I don't know what is wrong with my xml file.

This is one of my xml file delow Annotations folder
Other xml files are in the same format.

```html
    <annotation>
        <filename>20221101-065756.jpg</filename>
        <folder>jetbot</folder>
        <source>
            <database>jetbot</database>
            <annotation>custom</annotation>
            <image>custom</image>
        </source>
        <size>
            <width>1280</width>
            <height>720</height>
            <depth>3</depth>
        </size>
        <segmented>0</segmented>
        <object>
            <name>jetbot</name>
            <pose>unspecified</pose>
            <truncated>0</truncated>
            <difficult>0</difficult>
            <bndbox>
                <xmin>100</xmin>
                <ymin>187</ymin>
                <xmax>514</xmax>
                <ymax>678</ymax>
            </bndbox>
        </object>
    </annotation>
```

Also, I checked my file route again and again, but there was no problem.
Any advice would be so appreciated.

Comment: You should provide a [mre]. Post the problematic XML file. It seems your dataset is corrupted. Why not downloading it again?

Comment: The example was to train the object detection model with custom dataset, the content you put on the link.
Follow the tutorial link that you referred to in the article
https://github.com/dusty-nv/jetson-inference After receiving git clone from this link, we used camera capture to collect datasets and retrain the pretrained model.
There was a problem while parsing files that match the name from the Accotations folder where the bounding box xml files are gathered from the file name list in dataset.

Comment: Did you prepare your dataset exactly the same format and structure as VOC2007 or VOC2012? Anyway it cannot be answered without a sample dataset. Make a small dataset of 2~3 samples, that reproduces the problem. Then you will find the problem. If not, post that dataset.

Comment: Thank you for your advice to me who lacks the experience of stack over flow. The post has been modified to reflect the corresponding information. I would really appreciate it if you could review it again based on the revised points.

Comment: I mean the 'format and structure of VOC dataset' to be that of all files in sub-directories 'Annotations', 'ImageSets', 'JPEGImages', etc.

Comment: I attached the dataset google drive open link, which is organized according to VOC structure, but as you advised, I have specified the structure once again in the text. Thank you.

Comment: Where is the link? You only posted links to pretrained models and git repository.

Comment: In addition to the two links listed at the top, the blue lettering in the body below is the link in the text.
But sir, when I changed the Jetpack version and started collecting images from scratch, the training process went smoothly! Thank you so much for your advice.